# Axios get in stock items

Tags: reactjs, filter, axios

I am trying to filter products whether it is available or not.

Not sure how to pass an axios request with ">" logic.

I've started to create an **Action**

```
export const listProductAvailable = () => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: PRODUCT_AVAILABLE_LIST_REQUEST,
  });
  try {
    const { data } = await Axios.get(`/api/products?countInStock>0`);
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_AVAILABLE_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_AVAILABLE_LIST_FAIL, payload: error.message });
  }
};
```

But I don't think that such a request is possible.

> const { data } = await Axios.get(`/api/products?countInStock>0`);

Also, I don't see myself changing my **Product Model** creating an isAvailable boolean field as it would be redundant with countInStock =0 or not.

Comment: Try using graphql, it is created by facebook for such use cases. Docs https://graphql.org/learn/

Comment: Thank you, I will try graphQl later. For now I have been able to get the desired result using filters. (example : Product.find(countInStock: { $gte: countInStock }) )